# Configure Hadoop to use S3 requester-pays-enabled

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, jets3t

I'm using Hadoop (via Spark), and need to access S3N content which is requester-pays.  Normally, this is done by enabling `httpclient.requester-pays-buckets-enabled = true` in `jets3t.properties`.  Yet, I've set this and Spark / Hadoop are ignoring it.  Perhaps I'm putting the `jets3t.properties` in the wrong place (`/usr/share/spark/conf/`).  How can I get Hadoop / Spark / JetS3t to access requestor-pays buckets?

*UPDATE: This is needed if you are outside Amazon EC2.  Within EC2, Amazon doesn't require requester-pays.  So, a crude workaround is to run out of EC2.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables and config files didn't work, but some manual code did: `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "PUTTHEKEYHERE")`

Comment: what is SC jn this context?

Answer (score 0):

The Spark system is made up of several JVMs (application, master, workers, executors), so setting properties can be tricky. You could use `System.getProperty()` before the file operation to check if the JVM where the code runs has loaded the right config. You could even use `System.setProperty()` to directly set it at that point instead of figuring out the config files.

Comment: Isn't using `System.setProperty()` from within the code too late, because JetS3t has already configured itself?

Comment: I don't know about JetS3t actually, my suggestion was just based on my struggles to set some properties in Spark. For JetS3t perhaps you can use `setRequesterPaysBucket()`: https://bitbucket.org/jmurty/jets3t/src/e9ca56dabe58b2a8ae35494b44f12a5f1baa83bd/src/org/jets3t/samples/CodeSamples.java?at=default#cl-902